# I am learning building App from React. - I am getting blank page when I am loading the webpage

Tags: reactjs

https://medium.com/cleverprogrammer/amazon-clone-using-react-the-ultimate-guide-fba2b36f3458
I am copying the code from this website only.

Comment: do you have installed all required dependencies?

Comment: dont blatantly copy paste code. Analize it. There could be one out of 100+ different issue thats causing it. But since you dont even know the code you yourself copy pasted - u cant provide us with anything. And without info - we can not know whats going on. Post an error that you are getting in console, post the components that are broken. give us something to work with other then saying 'it dosent work'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.